# Use F12 to open Developer Tools on Chrome

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, shortcut

I have already configured so that F keys act as "standard function keys" (just regular F1-F12).

How can I configure F12 to open the Developer Tools on Chrome?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- Open Keyboard Shortcuts Preferences
- Click "Mission Control" from the list
- Untick "Show Dashboard" (disable default beahviour of <kbd>F12</kbd>)
- Click "Application Shortcuts" from the list
- Click the "+" below the right-hand list
- Select Google Chrome from the drop down list
- In "Menu Title", type Developer Tools
- Click in "Keyboard Shortcut", then press <kbd>F12</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Didn't know about this amazing way to customize shortcuts! Thanks!